# ConcurrentModificationException even with Iterator

Tags: java, android, concurrency, hashmap

I am using a HashMap and using an iterator to remove the elements from the map.

```
new Handler(SdkContext.getApplicationContext().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {

                    Iterator<Map.Entry<Placement, Aunit>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<Placement, Aunit> entry = iterator.next();
                        entry.getValue().deInit();
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

But even this code is causing `ConcurrentModificationException` only sometimes. It is both thread safe and i am using `Iterator` also. 
So how can it cause the exception?

Comment: Are you starting multiple threads concurrently? Try synchronizing on the `Map` instead of on the anonymous `Runnable` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most collections/iterators are not thread safe.
You seem to be trying to get around this by calling `synchronized`. This is not a bad idea, if you synchronized *every* access (read and write) to the collection (your `map`) using the same *monitor object*.

In your sample code, you are using `this` as monitor/lock object (referring to the instance of your anonymous inner class of type `Runnable`). That's not appropriate, as you aren't using the same object when you manipulate the collection elsewhere: `this` is a different object every time you call your code and it's not handed to the calling code.

So, to do this right, you will have to synchronize *every* access to the `map`. And, you have to use the same synchronization object every time (you could use the `map` itself). You might also want to read up on how synchronization really works.

Comment: Okay. But if i use `this` of my top level class to synchronize every modifying operation on the `HashMap`, then it should not throw the exception.Right? Or a ConcurrentHashMap should also work in this case?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` should work. I would not use `this` of the top level class, because it will be rather coarse locking. Also, frankly I have no idea whether you have one or multiple instances of that class. `ConcurrentHashMap` is the better route.

Comment: Okay. BTW, that class is a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

when iterating through map, we can not change the structure of the map by adding or removing the elements from it. Here you are trying to remove the elements from the map which throws ConcurrentModifactionException. Here you get the synchronization on Runnable object but not on map. The below code will give you synchronized map or you can use ConcurrentMap provided.

```
   Collections.synchronizedMap(map)
```

Comment: We can of course do structural modifications using an iterator.

Comment: A `synchronizedMap` does not prevent modifications from one thread while another thread is looping through an iterator.